# How to send install intent to Android Wear watch from handheld

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, android-wear-2.0

Basically, I want to send a request from a handheld to the watch to open the app link in Google Play so they can install the app on their watch. I would also need to get back a result once they have installed the app on the watch so I don't continue to send the request every time they open the app on the handheld.

I know this is possible as this app does it... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appfour.wearlauncher&hl=en

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Here are the Google docs I followed...

https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/standalone-apps.html

Sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearVerifyRemoteApp